# How to do Multiple API request at same time in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a problem to send multiple Requests from different pages in Angular 7 and Typescript .

Example :

I have a page called Email , from this page i need to send 1000 Emails one by one and Update status in a variable and this should done in background (once i click send then Email form should close) , then i have navigated to another page to do my other stuff ( fetching or posting data to another API ) , in this case i am not able to call second API request till complete the previous (Email) Request.

below is the code which i send to APi

```
   public SendMultileEmails(Emaildata: any, Listcount: number) {

    if (Emaildata != undefined && Emaildata != [] && Emaildata != '') {
        if (Listcount >= this.Emailcount) {
            var Invoice = Emaildata[this.Emailcount];
            var transactionName = Invoice.transactionName;
            var salesHeaderID = Invoice.salesHeaderID;
            var customerurl = '/Api/MultipleEmail?trnasactiontype=' + transactionName + '&Headerid=' + salesHeaderID;
            this.http.get(customerurl)
                .subscribe(result => {
                    this.Emailcount = this.Emailcount + 1;
                    this.SentEmailcount = this.Emailcount;
                    this.SendMultileEmails(Emaildata,Listcount);
                },
                    err => console.log(err)
                );
        }


    }


}
```

Is there a way to do this task . please guide me.

Thanks

Victor.

Comment: use forkJoin and this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328087/angular-rxjs-forkjoin-completion-progress/58329721#58329721

Comment: Try `concatMap` operator to call API sequentially,

Comment: @Eliseo : Thank you for your reply , if i cal  with in same .ts file then i can use forkjoin , but in my case both are different .ts files . If this is Work to my scenario then please give any example .... Thanks

Comment: well, my comment in code, see the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do some like:

```
//create an array of obs
const obs[]=Emaildata.map(data=>{
     const transactionName = data.transactionName;
     const salesHeaderID = data.salesHeaderID;
     const customerurl = '/Api/MultipleEmail?trnasactiontype=' + transactionName +
           '&Headerid=' + salesHeaderID;   
     return this.http.get(customerurl)
})

forkJoin(obs.map(o => o.pipe(tap(() => this.Emailcount++))))
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo, i will try this and come back with status ...